# Pattern matching on base class and all derived classes in Scala

Tags: generics, scala, types, pattern-matching

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
def a(b: Any) = {
  b match {
     case x: Seq[String] => println("x")
  }
}

// somewhere else

a(List("b"))
```

As a result I'd love to see "x" being printed, and I don't.

Basically I want to match against a type/trait and cover all of the objects whose types derive from/implement such type/trait, with the trait being Seq and the type parameter being known in advance.
Since I'm a scala novice I'm quite stuck, however.

Ideas?

Comment: Well, I don't know about you, but it certainly does print `x` here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't check against parameterized types because of type erasure. See this question why there will be a warning: [Warning about an unchecked type argument in this Scala pattern match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278330/warning-about-an-unchecked-type-argument-in-this-scala-pattern-match)

Another question and its answers tell you how to get around that: [How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can't I get the type parameter of my collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete)

Nevertheless your code works fine, when you don't check against type parameters:

```
scala> List("a") match { case _: Seq[_] => 1 case _ => 2 }
res0: Int = 1
```

Comment: *You can't check against parameterized types* There is one little exception -- Arrays

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that you're doing it wrong. Instead of pattern matching, what you want here is a type class, or some other mechanism (class methods) that can do type-based dynamic dispatch. Using pattern matching to perform your own type-based dispatch makes for messy code and thwarts type safety.

Here's a quick and common example of a type class in Scala. First, define a trait that the class of types has in common:

```
trait Ord[T] { def compare (x: T, y: T): Boolean }
```

In your case, you would want the `a` method to be the trait's method. Then, for each type that you want to belong to the type class, create an implicit object for it:

```
implicit object ordInt extends Ord[Int] {
  def compare (x: Int, y: Int) = x <= y
}
```

Here I've made `Int` an instance of my `Ord` type class. Now you can write methods that rely on the interface that your type class provides. The method should accept the specific type class object implicitly, like so:

```
def sort[T](xs: List[T])(implicit ord: Ord[T]) = {
```

you can then make use of the special methods on the type class by invoking it on the implicit object.

```
def sort[T](xs: List[T])(implicit ord: Ord[T]) = {
  def insert(y: T, ys: List[T]): List[T] = ys match {
    case Nil => List(y)
    case z :: zs =>
      if (ord.compare(y,z)) { y::z::zs } // <--- here I use ord.compare
      else { z :: insert(y, zs) }
  }
  xs.foldRight(List[T]())(insert _)
}
```

And voila! We have type-directed dispatch, without losing type safety. Want to sort a list of Ints? No problem. Trying to sort a list of something that doesn't have an Ord instance? The compiler will stop you from shooting yourself in the foot.