# Extract sublist of descendants in Scala

Tags: scala, casting, scala-collections, descendant

I have a  `class Foo extends Bar` and a `List` or other collection of base class:

```
val bars: Iterable[Bar]
```

I need to extract all `Foo` elements from the collection. The following is the code:

```
val fooes: Iterable[Foo] = bars
    .filter(x => Try(x.isInstanceOf[Foo]).isSuccess))
    .map(_.isInstanceOf[Foo])
```

Is there conciser approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
val fooes: Iterable[Foo] = bars.collect{case foo:Foo => foo}
```

The `.collect()` method takes a partial-function as its parameter. In this case the function is defined only for `Foo` types. All others are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of possible rewrites worth remembering in general

- `filter` followed by `map` as `collect`
- `isInstanceOf` followed by `asInstanceOf` as pattern match with [typed pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3412222/5205022)

Hence the following [discouraged](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html#lst:is-as-instanceof) style

```
bars
  .filter { _.isInstanceOf[Foo] }
  .map    { _.asInstanceOf[Foo] }
```

can be rewritten to idiomatic style

```
bars collect { case foo: Foo => foo }
```

> ...writing type tests and casts is rather verbose in Scala. That's
>   intentional, because it is not encouraged practice. You are usually
>   better off using a pattern match with a typed pattern. That's
>   particularly true if you need to do both a type test and a type cast,
>   because both operations are then rolled into a single pattern match.

Note the nature of typed pattern is still just [runtime type check followed by runtime type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7279746/5205022), that is, it merely represent nicer stylistic clothing not an increase in type safety. For example

```
scala -print -e 'lazy val result: String = (42: Any) match { case v: String => v }'
```

expands to something like

```
<synthetic> val x1: Object = scala.Int.box(42);
if (x1.$isInstanceOf[String]()) {
  <synthetic> val x2: String = (x1.$asInstanceOf[String]());
  ...
}
```

where we clearly see type check `isInstanceOf` followed by type cast `asInstanceOf`.